# openlims - Sem aparecer corpo nas páginas poderá ser configuração de permissões?

Tags: php, postgresql

Bom dia,

Instalei o Open-lims para testar o sistema, at+e aqui tudo bem, mas agora deparo-me com um problema, só me aparece o header das páginas sem corpo.

Parece tudo ok, mas por alguma razão não aparece o resto da informação.

Alguém poderá dar uma ajuda.

Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]